# Android - Access Root Directory

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, directory, root

I'm planning on developing an Android app within Unity.

But I want to know if it's possible to access the Android's root directory?

I know that Android provides a data folder under the directory:

> Storage Device > Android > data > com.MyApp.Unity > files > MyStuff

But would it be possible to access other directories, or locations within the device? For example a folder within the root:

> Storage Device > MyFolder > MyStuff

Or maybe access Movies from the Movies Directory:

> Storage Device > Movies > MyStuff

Thanks,
Ollie.

Comment: Yes that is possible. And you are not referring to Androids root directory but to root directories of storage volumes.

Comment: @greenapps. Thank you for your feedback. How would one access these? Does it require special permission from the user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

...to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

When I did this, I managed to copy some files (accidentally) to the root folder you've mentioned.